# How to get a list view of columns and % of nans/nulls in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, data-cleaning

I am running a simple EDA on my dataset that has 59K rows and 21 columns. What I would like to see is a list of all columns and the % of the nulls/nans. I ran the following code in Jupyter in my virtual machine:

```
#Checking nulls by column
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
null_df = datingDF.select([(count(when(isnan(c) | col(c).isNull(), c))/count(lit(1))).alias(c) for c in datingDF.columns])
null_df.show()
```

The output is really cluttered and not a clean list (see attached)[image]

Comment: If you do not like the output of show, print data by yourself. You collect your dataframe, and use `print`. Or just copy paste to excel, you'll have there a nice display

Comment: It's not about not liking, I want to be able to see the null % for each column to decide how i want to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `null_df.show()` with :

```py
for i,j in null_df.first().asDict().items():
    print(i,j)
```