# show() for large number of columns in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I am working with a dataframe that was 20 columns. When I try to display output using .show() after manipulations, due to the large number of columns its not very easy to read. What's the best way to get a compact view of all columns?

Thanks
SS

Comment: are you using the shell?

Comment: I am not sure what shell means. I am quite new to Spark :)

Comment: Where are you writing the code? Are you using terminal or zeppelin or jupyter notebook?

Comment: That's a duplicate of your previous question : [How to get a list view of columns and % of nans/nulls in Pyspark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64204875/how-to-get-a-list-view-of-columns-and-of-nans-nulls-in-pyspark)

Comment: I am using Jupyter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use display to show the dataframe. You can use it by `display(df)`

More source of this you can find in [here](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/visualizations/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

the `display()` function is what you want.
If your dataframe is named `df`, you'll call the function as such:
`display(df)` .